# In Factory functions are object names and 'this' keyword often or always interchangeable?

Tags: javascript, this

The following code doesn't throw an error but I'm not entirely sure why.
In the `doubleIt` method I use the name of the object, `returnObject` instead of `this`.

After `newInstance` is instantiated I would expect that the term `returnObject` would be copied into the new `doubleIt` method.  Because `returObject` only exists in the factory function if `doubleIt` was called from `newInstance` it would confuse the JS engine and throw an error.  However it doesn't, it works fine.  Why does this still work?

```js
"use strict"

function factoryFunction(x) {
    let returnObject = {
        oneParameter: x,
        doubleIt: () => returnObject.oneParameter * 2

        // doubleIt: () => this.oneParameter * 2
        // Why don't I have to use the 'this' version?
    }
    return returnObject;
}

let newInstance = factoryFunction(10);

console.log(newInstance.doubleIt());
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way javascript deals with situations like this is described in painstaking detail in documents like [this](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-relational-operators-runtime-semantics-evaluation).

That's not easy to parse for most humans, but the gist is that the left hand side of an assignment is processed first. So in your example `returnObject` gets a reference to the object. After than the value of the object is evaluated. So it sees that you are using `returnObject` which it already has a reference to and is able to lookup the `oneParameter` property at runtime. All this is captured in a [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures), which means the returned object has access to the name `returnObject`.

To show that it's actually evaluating at runtime, you can change `oneParameter` and then call the function. It works as expected:

```js
"use strict"

function factoryFunction(x) {
    let returnObject = {
        oneParameter: x,
        doubleIt: () => returnObject.oneParameter * 2

        // doubleIt: () => this.oneParameter * 2
        // Why don't I have to use the 'this' version?
    }
    return returnObject;
}

let newInstance = factoryFunction(10);

newInstance.oneParameter = 100

console.log(newInstance.doubleIt());
```

Also, `returnObject` is not copied into the new `doubleIt` — `doubleIt` just has a reference that points to `returnObject`.

Comment: Holy smokes!  Ok so when the new object is created returnObject becomes a reference to a position.  Is using the object name instead of `this` a legitimate way to construct that statement or is it a hacky mess likely to crash at the next update to the V8 engine?  Thanks so much!

Comment: Well, you can't really use `this` the way you have it with the arrow function. If you use a regular function expression it will work. But if you do that, then  the value of `this` will depend on how the function is called, whereas explicitly using `returnObject` will always be the same. p.s. I don't think it's hacky.

Answer (score 2):

A closure captures its environment variables. Since returnObject was defined as a variable outside the closure, it will be captured by the closure.

What will happen in this case, is that a circular reference will be created where the closure doubleIt() will have a reference to returnObject and returnObject will have a reference to doubleIt().

With regard to "this", in your example, it refers to the window object, since the factory function was not invoked with "new". If it is invoked with "new", then it will refer to the factoryFunction. However, it will never refer to returnObject, since returnObject itself was never invoked with "new". In order to have "this" point to returnObject within doubleIt(), you will need to define a function for returnObject that will be invoked with new. The following snippet will work if you invoke factoryFunction with or without "new":

```js
function factoryFunction(x) {
    let returnObject = function(x) {
        this.oneParameter = x;
        this.doubleIt = () => this.oneParameter * 2;
    };
    
    return new returnObject(x);
}

let newInstance = factoryFunction(10);
let anotherNewInstance = new factoryFunction(10);

console.log(newInstance.doubleIt());
console.log(anotherNewInstance.doubleIt());
```

Comment: `this` works just fine with `returnObject` if you define it with a function expression rather than fat arrow. Just us: `doubleIt: function(){return this.oneParameter * 2}` `this` will refer to the calling context, so it you call it `newInstance.doubleIt()` it will work fine.

Comment: Yes, that's right. If there's no need for an arrow function, then a normal function will suit just fine. Thanks @Mark_M

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript object orientation is different from "classic" object orientation. When you create the new object returnObject is assumed as "this", since it is the object.